# Facebook iOS share open graph story with custom buttons

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

What I want to achieve is something like the below one. Adding a custom button next to the "Like" and "Comment". (Just like the button "Adopt a baby").

[image: reference]

---

Here is the code I have written for basic facebook sharing. I have read though the facebook documentations, and have tried several methods but all failed. I really have no idea how to add an additional action button.

Does anyone ever write something like this? Can you kindly share you experience? Many thanks.

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
[action setObject:@"http://samples.ogp.me/350421611727583" forKey:@"discount"];

NSLog(@"action >> %@",action);
[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/istampemobii:get"
                                   graphObject:action
                             completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                 id result,
                                                 NSError *error) {
                                 // handle the result
                             }];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called an "action link". You can read about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/action-links/